Dividir valores seleccionados de combobox en diferentes registros powerapps
Tengo una lista en Sharepoint, con tres columnas: Incidente, causas, Consecuencias.En powerapps tengo un formulario con un control para cada columna, dónde:
Incidente es un inputtex Causas y consecuencias son combobox con selección múltiple.
Necesito que cada elemento seleccionado en cada combobox se genere como un registro. En la tabla. Específicamente poder hacer lo mismo quela función dividir en filas de PowerQuery.
Ejemplo:
Inputtex1: "Caída de persona"
Combobox1 (causas): {"Piso mojado", "Falta de señalización"}
Combobox2 (consecuencias): {"ruptura de pierna", "Demandas"}
Al hacer el patch, necesito que esté nuevo registro quedé de la siguiente manera:
`Table`(
  {
   `Incidente`:"Caída de persona",
   `Causas`: "piso mojado",
   `Consecuencias`: "ruptura de pierna"
   },

   {
   `Incidente`:"Caída de persona",
   `Causas`: "piso mojado",
   `Consecuencias`: "Demandas"
   },
   {
   `Incidente`:"Caída de persona",
   `Causas`: "Falta de señalización",
   `Consecuencias`: "ruptura de pierna"
   },
   {
   `Incidente`:"Caída de persona",
   `Causas`: "Falta de señalización",
   `Consecuencias`: "Demandas"
   },

Intenté hacerlo con:
Forall(Combobox1.Selecteditems,
Patch(List,Defauls(List),
  {Incidente: inputex.tex,
   Causas: ThisRecord.Value,
   Consecuencias:Combobox2.SelectedItems})

Esto me soluciona el problema, cuando es un solo combobox, pero cuando tengo más de 1 con selección no me es funcional.
